# Non EU-citizen spouse working rights

Tags: germany, eu-citizens, marriage, working, italy

I'm non EU citizen and I will marry Italian girl soon. 
So I need to know if I've the right to work in another EU country without the need of that my wife move me.

I want to work in Germany and my future wife can't move now because she need to get her diploma first.

Answer (score 7):

A non-EU family member of an EU citizen enjoys freedom of movement only when accompanying or joining the EU citizen.  You would not have a right to move to Germany or to work there unless your wife were also living in Germany.